# How to convert(or Dwonload) binary data which is stored in MongoDB to a PDF file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Here's my code

```
download = function(req, res) {
let fileId = req.param('imageid');
//read from mongodb
filesColl.model.find({fileId : fileId}).exec(function(err, items){
    if (err){
        console.log('error')
        return res.apiError('database error', err);            
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type':'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=some_file.pdf',
        'Content-Length':items[0].file.length});
    res.end(items[0].file, 'binary');
});};
```

Help me... I'm trying this for some hours. still i can't able to get the result
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i can able to download pdf file in client side. but its saving as **response.pdf.pdf**. When i open the pdf file, i'm getting error.

Comment: Here is code, how am saving in mongoDB

`const binaryImg = new Buffer(body.file, 'base64');            
            let fileItem = new filesColl.model({
                fileName: body.fileName,
                file: binaryImg});
            fileItem.save(function(err, items){
              if (err){
                return res.apiError('database error', err);    
              }
              console.log("File uploaded");
              res.apiResponse({post: reconSuppModel});
            });`